# How can I improve the performance of this architecture?

Tags: performance, web, architecture, cluster-computing, server-side

I'm running a website that is CPU heavy due to a lot of thumbnailing of images.

This is how I currently do things:

1. User uploads image to server
2. Server keeps a copy, and stores the image on Amazon S3
3. When an thumbnail is requested, server uses the local copy to generate it, and then stores it on S3; then gives the S3 URL to the client
4. Subsequent requests are optimized like this: Server caches S3 URL in memcached, so it won't do the work again; server never generates a thumbnail again if the file exists; the server uses mid-sized thumbnails to generate small-sized one, so not to work with large files of not necessary

Now, I'm hosting on a Linode 4G instance (8 cores with 4x priority, 4GB RAM), and despite my optiomizations and having a memcached hit ratio of 70%, my average CPU is 170%. I'm constantly seeing all 8 CPUs working with frequent spikes of 100% for many of them at the same time.

I'm using nginx and gunicorn to serve a Django application, and the thumbnails are generated with PIL.

**How can I improve this architecture?**

I was thinking about a few possibilities:

#1. Easiest: add a second identical server with a load balancer in front, so that they'd share the load.

The problem with this is that the two servers would not share the local image cache. Could I solve this by placing such share on a network drive, or would the latency ultimately hinder the gains?

#2. A little harder: split the thumbnailing code out of my app, as a separate webservice, that would run on a second server. This way the main application and database would not suffer from high CPU usage, and the web pages would be served fast. The thumbnails are anyway already served asynchronously with JavaScript

Can anyone recommend some other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your performance problems come from thumbnails? OK, I suppose you've checked that.

You can downsize and upload the 2 thumbnails to S3 immediately (or shortly) after user uploaded the image. This way you should be able to save unnecessary CPU load you're now wasting for every HTTP request checking those thumbnails and doing IPC with memcached.

Comment: The thing is that old images might not have their thumbnails yet, so I still need to check if the file exists on S3, and if not, generate it. Are you suggesting I save the thumbnail locations in the database?

Comment: Can't you run a one-time script to generate all thumbnails for the old images? Checking for S3 existence is even worse than local IPC to memcached, it's a network call. And a typical astrobin.com page has dozens of images.

Comment: It's over 60k images... and I'd have to download them, generate the thumbnails, and upload again. I think it will be costly. Besides, I moved to a system that allows me to generate thumbnails on the fly so that I can have flexibility of changing thumbnail sizes if I change layout, or easily add new sizes on different pages. PS: good detective work finding AstroBin :)

Comment: I've looked at the network traffic in Dragonfly. For every small thumbnail you do GET thumb/thumb/ -> HTTP 302 to CDN. That many HTTP requests are expensive, especially with your Python HTTP stack. Instead of doing that, you could use JSON-RPC to fetch the addresses of many thumbnails at once (e.g. the complete row).
And by the way, the main page takes 5-10 seconds to generate. Looks like you have too much code running per-request, and too few data cached across clients.

Comment: You've read my mind... basically if you try again, you will see that I've minimized the number of HTTP requests. In my templatetag that generates one image, now I'm checking memcached for a cache entry on the URL of that thumbnail. If it's present, then I serve the S3 URL directly, otherwise I do the asynchronous HTTP request.

Concerning the long time for the requests... I'm simply stumped: I've tried django-debug-toolbar and I my front page is only spending 170ms in SQL queries. And I even profiled it using a profiling middleware for Django, and everything looked fast.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to help me find out what's taking so long?

Answer (score 0):

In a way your problem is a "good" problem to have (or at least it could have been a lot worse), in that there are no dependencies between separate image resizing tasks, so you can trivially distribute them over multiple servers. A few comments:

1. Have you checked to see if there is anything you can do to make the image resizing operations faster? (Google brought this up, don't know if it's any help: http://dmmartins.appspot.com/blog/speeding-up-image-resizing-with-python-and-pil) Even if you still find you need to add more servers, anything you can do to make each resize operation more efficient will make each server go farther.
2. If your users keep becoming more and more, you will eventually need to "scale out", but for the short term, it is possible you could solve the problem simply by paying another $80 for the next "tier" of service (8 cores at 8x priority).
3. Is image resizing really your app's only bottleneck? If image resizing was "free", how much further can you scale on your existing server before rendering pages, running DB queries, etc. would limit throughput? If you don't know, it would be good to do some simulated load testing and find out. I ask because if rendering pages, DB queries, etc. are also bottlenecks, or are soon to become bottlenecks, you are going to have to distribute the app anyways. In that case, you might as well keep thumbnailing in the main app, and distribute it right now, rather than making your thumbnailing run as a web service on a 2nd server.
4. Regardless of whether you distribute the main app, or split out thumbnailing into a separate app on a different server, you need some kind of authoritative store to keep track of where each thumbnail is kept on S3. You can keep that information in memcached, in a database, or wherever you want. It doesn't really matter. Even if you keep it in memcached, that doesn't mean you can't share the cache between 2 servers -- 1 server can connect to a memcached instance running on the other server.

You asked if "the latency" of checking a cache which is held on a different server will "hinder the gains". I don't think you need to worry about that. Your problem is throughput, not latency. Those high-latency network operations parallelize very well. So if you just service more requests in parallel, you can still make full use of your CPUs (which is the resource bottleneck right now).